# Can I trigger cleanup on leaving scope?

Tags: ruby

Sometimes I find myself needing to attach context to a particular scope, releasing it once the scope has exited, e.g.

```
User.all do |u|
  custom_logger.with_context({ user_id: u.id }) do
    # .. some code
    custom_logger.warn('something happened')
    # .. some more code
  end
end
```

You see this pattern in rails, e.g.

```
I18n.with_locale(...) do
  # some code
end
```

I would like a similar behavior, but where cleanup could happen once I exit the current scope, e.g.

```
User.all do |u|
  custom_logger.set_scoped_context({ user_id: u.id })
  # .. some code
  custom_logger.warn('something happened')
  # .. some more code
end
```

In the code above, I would like the behavior to be similar to the earlier example, but where context is scoped to the surrounding scope.

Is this possible to achieve in ruby?

Comment: No good ways come to mind immediately. Is there a reason you want to do this beyond the style difference?

Comment: I don't think context should be aware of its surrounding scope. Using a block is the proper way to handle this.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point here, but the way you normally provide context to a block is to have it run against a class that encapsulates that context...?

Comment: @JKillian, style + curiosity.

Comment: @Stefan, agreed. I still want to know if it is possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing global state and expecting some hidden abstraction to cleanup/reset state is very error prone. If you don't like the block style, I'd recommend creating a new logger with the current context instead of changing the global state:

```
User.all do |u|
  scoped_logger = custom_logger.with_context({ user_id: u.id })
  # .. some code
  scoped_logger.warn('something happened')
  # .. some more code
end
```